# Jasper Reports: How to conditionally set the textbox style?

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible in Jasper Reports to conditionally set a textbox style? If yes, how?

Please note that I'm aware of conditional styles, but I do not need a style which varies on a condition, but set the proper style using a different condition for each textbox (of course I could create a conditional style for each textbox, but that would be a real PITA...).

I'm using Jasper Reports 3.7.6 and the Jasper Studio Eclipse plugin.

Thanks

**Use case example pseudocode:**

```
bean1 {
    f1
    f2
}

bean2 {
    cond1
    cond2
}

<textbox1 style="(bean2.cond1 ? style1 : style2)">
    bean1.f1
</textbox1>
<textbox2 style="(bean2.cond2 ? style1 : style2)">
    bean1.f2
</textbox2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself: it turns out that it is not possible to set conditional style the way I needed. I ended up with duplicating each text fields (a copy for each style), then setting the visibility upon the condition. Boring and time consuming, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't define a generic style. See page 135 of the iReport Ultimate Guide:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/ireport-ultimate-guide:

> Please note that the conditions cannot be generic, 
>   for instance, you cannot set a condition like “if the number is positive” or “if the string is 
>   null
>   .” You must be very specific, 
>   specifying, for example, that a 
>   particular value (field, parameter, variable or 
>   any expression involving them) must be positive
>   or 
>   null, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, but as said I'm not looking for conditional styles. I added an example to clarify my problem.

Comment: Is each style based on a value in the textbox (e.g. style1 = red text if the textbox value > X)? Or is it based on another value (e.g. style1 = red text if another textbox > X)? And are style1 and style2 defined the same for both textbox1 and textbox2?

Comment: It is based on a "sidecar map". Basically, I want to highlight (field by field) the differences between two beans. ATM I'm passing the bean to print and a map which holds the fields changed (`{f1=true, f2=false}`).